# nodejs shallow git clone using simple-git

Tags: node.js, git, npm, shallow-clone

I'm trying to create shallow clone using [simple-git](https://github.com/steveukx/git-js). I'm trying to create an equivalent of this command: `git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/steveukx/git-js.git`. My code is as follows:

```
const git = require('simple-git')()

const repoURL = 'https://github.com/steveukx/git-js.git';
const localPath= './git-js';
const  options = ['--depth', '1'];

const handlerFn = () => {
    console.log('DONE')
};

git.clone(repoURL, localPath, options, handlerFn());
```

I've specified `--depth 1` in `options`, but the code copies the entire repo history, it seems to completely ignore the options given. Am I doing this correctly, what can cause this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging the issue was in  `git.clone(repoURL, localPath, options, handlerFn());`, you have to pass the reference to function instead of actual callback, like this `git.clone(repoURL, localPath, options, handlerFn);`.

The full implementation is bellow:

```
const git = require('simple-git')();
const fs = require('fs')
const url = require('url');

this.gitURL = 'https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git';

const localURL = url.parse(this.gitURL);
const localRepoName = (localURL.hostname + localURL.path)
.replace('com', '')
.replace('/', '')
.replace('/', '.')
.replace('.git', '')

this.localPath = `./${localRepoName}`;
this.options = ['--depth', '1'];
this.callback = () => {
    console.log('DONE')
}

if (fs.existsSync(this.localPath)) {
    // something
} else {
    git.outputHandler((command, stdout, stderr) => {
            stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
            stderr.pipe(process.stderr)

            stdout.on('data', (data) => {
                // Print data
                console.log(data.toString('utf8'))
            })
        })
        .clone(this.gitURL, this.localPath, this.options, this.callback)
}
```